# Try-with-resources should be used

Tags: java

How to convert below code to JAVA 8 - try-with-resource. I have written this code in java 6,i have upgraded java 6 to java 8 - Sonar giving Blocker message "Try-with-resources should be used"

```
 public void archivingTheFile(String zipFile){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        for(String file : this.fileList){
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid resource leaks, it is always best practice to close the resource objects (like your `FileOutputStream`, etc..) in the `finally` block. The reason is that finally block gets executed even upon exception and **the resource will never get leaked or escaped**.

The important thing in your code is that you are NOT closing the resources in the `finally` block i.e., they can escape & produce leaks.

Instead of you closing the resoruces in the `finally` block, 
**try-with-resources is just a syntactic sugar to close any resource class (which implement `AutoCloseable`) objects** (this is introduced in Java1.7)

You can apply **try-with-resources** concept as shown below for your code with inline comments:

```
public void archivingTheFile(String zipFile){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            //wrap the resources inside try(....)
            try(FileOutputStream fos = 
                        new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
                    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);) {
                for(String file : this.fileList){
                    ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
                    zos.putNextEntry(ze);

                    //wrap this resource as well inside try(....)
                    try(FileInputStream in = 
                      new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file)){
                        int len;
                        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    } catch(IOException ex) {
                         LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException ex){
                LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
            }
        }
```

I suggest you look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) for more details and understand this concept.

Answer (score 2):

A side note: try-with-resources statements were introduced in Java 7.

The resources to be disposed of in this case are the `FileOutputStream`, the `ZipOutputStream` and the `FileInputStream`. Formally speaking, they can be used in try-with-resources because they implement `AutoCloseable`. So you can write the code as follows:

**Java 7+**

```
public void archivingTheFile(String zipFile){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        for(String file : this.fileList){
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file)) {
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
        zos.closeEntry();

    }catch(IOException ex){
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to call `FileOutputStream.close()` or `FileInputStream.close()`.

**Why is Sonar telling you to use these statements?**

It's because they are the best way to deal with objects that represent resources such as IO streams *while ensuring that they are closed at the end*. Otherwise, resources may leak in your system. With Java 6 code, the alternative is to use `try-catch-finally`:

**Java 6**

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ZipOutputStream zos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
    ...
} catch(IOException ex){
    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
} finally {
    if(fos != null) {
       fos.close();
    }
    if(zos != null) {
       zos.close();
    }
}
```

You can read about the try-with-resources statement from the Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html.

Comment: reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I increased the copy buffer. On file system operation the minimum buffer size should be 4094 as this is the block size on most OS/file-systems.

```
public void archivingTheFile(String zipFile) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile); ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {

        for (String file : this.fileList) {
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file)) {
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
public void archivingTheFile(String zipFile){
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        for(String file : this.fileList){
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file)) {
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    } catch(IOException ex){
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while zipping file",ex);
    }
}
```